# How to set a downstream task after finish of 2 Tasks

Tags: airflow

I am running tasks(T1 and T2) in parallel. How do i set a downstream task T3 which depends on both T1 and T2 being finished successfully

`[T1,T2].set_downstream(T3)`

But, getting following error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_downstream'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is serval ways you can implement task dependancies, [Read - Managing Dependencies](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/managing-dependencies/) or just see the examples below.

```
T1.set_downstream(T3)
T2.set_downstream(T3)
```

or

`T3.set_upstream([T1, T2])`

or

`[T1, T2] >> T3`

Answer (score 1):

## How to set up Upstream Downstream Dependency :

Lets take this example : It contains 3 tasks , so you can set the
upstream-downstream dependency  like this :

[t1, t2] >> t3

```
t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='t1',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=call_me,
)

t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='push_by_returning',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=call_me_too(),
)

t3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='puller',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=status_chcker,
    trigger_rule="all_done"
)

   

[t1, t2] >> t3
```

### How to set up condition for downstream job trigger :

trigger_rule="all_done"

There are multiple trigger rule based on which the downstream jobs can be triggered.

- all_success: (default) all parents have succeeded
- all_failed: all parents are in a failed or upstream_failed state
- all_done: all parents are done with their execution
- one_failed: fires as soon as at least one parent has failed, it does
  not wait for all parents to be done
- one_success: fires as soon as at least one parent succeeds, it does
  not wait for all parents to be done
- none_failed: all parents have not failed (failed or upstream_failed)
  i.e. all parents have succeeded or been skipped
- none_skipped: no parent is in a skipped state, i.e. all parents are
  in a success, failed, or upstream_failed state
- dummy: dependencies are just for show, trigger at will